# Angularfire2: make nested API calls before returning the auth state observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm using AngularFire2 in my Angular2 application. I'm working now on the authentication part my question is related to "listening" to the auth state changes. I'm already subscribing to the af.auth observable in some components. And i'm mapping the output to boolean as below:

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.af.auth.map((user) => user?true:false)
}
```

Now i want to do more processing in this function and still returns an observable of boolean.
1. I need to check if the user is signed in, if so i need to
2. Get the user info from the db. and save to local storage
3. If no record exists i'll create a new user then save the data in the local storage.

I have been trying to implement it using nested observables with nested subscriptions but i get errors in the other components listening to this auth state changes due to the timing of the different observables callback functions. So i figured out that this function should be executed in an atomic manner so i started to play with the rxjs operators specifically the mergeMap operator but i'm not able to get it to compile right due to bad return value. Here is the final code.

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
let _user;
this.af.auth.mergeMap((user) => {
  _user = user;
  if (!user) {
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
  this.userService.getUserProfile(user['uid']).take(1).mergeMap((userData) => {
    if (userData.$exists()) {
      // user already created so save to local storage
      this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(new User(userData['displayName'], userData['email'], userData['uid'], userData['mode'], undefined, undefined));
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {
      // No user created so create one then save to local storage
      let newUser = new User(_user.auth.displayName, _user.auth.email, _user.uid, undefined, undefined, undefined);
      Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<void>>(this.userService.createUser(newUser))).mergeMap(
        () => {
          this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(newUser);
          return Observable.of(true);
        })
    }
  })
})
```

}

I'm getting this error:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

I'm not sure where this error comes from. I'm returning a value in each condition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: may i ask...why are you using the `return` statement instead of callbacks?

Comment: You're missing a `return` before `Observable.fromPromise`

Comment: @paulpdaniels: Thanks for your response. I added the return in the mergeMap function subscribing to this observable from promise.

Comment: @ymz: Thanks for your response. The isAuthenticated function should return an observable of boolean. So i'm trying to reduce all observables in all branches to the required type.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable#mergeMap` operator needs to return an `Observable`, and you're missing to return it at two places. Here is your code updated:

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
let _user;
return this.af.auth.mergeMap((user) => {
  _user = user;
  if (!user) {
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
  return this.userService.getUserProfile(user['uid']).take(1).mergeMap((userData) => {
    if (userData.$exists()) {
      // user already created so save to local storage
      this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(new User(userData['displayName'], userData['email'], userData['uid'], userData['mode'], undefined, undefined));
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {
      // No user created so create one then save to local storage
      let newUser = new User(_user.auth.displayName, _user.auth.email, _user.uid, undefined, undefined, undefined);
      return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<void>>(this.userService.createUser(newUser))).mergeMap(
        () => {
          this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(newUser);
          return Observable.of(true);
        })
    }
  })
})
```

}

Comment: Many Thanks for your response. It helped a lot. But i added extra return at this.af.auth to get it working.

Comment: Yep, I see, actually it was missing at three places :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
let _user;
return this.af.auth.mergeMap((user) => {
  _user = user;
  if (!user) {
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
  return this.userService.getUserProfile(user['uid']).take(1).mergeMap((userData) => {
    if (userData.$exists()) {
      // user already created so save to local storage
      this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(new User(userData['displayName'], userData['email'], userData['uid'], userData['mode'], undefined, undefined));
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {
      // No user created so create one then save to local storage
      let newUser = new User(_user.auth.displayName, _user.auth.email, _user.uid, undefined, undefined, undefined);
      return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<void>>(this.userService.createUser(newUser))).mergeMap(
        () => {
          this.userService.saveUserProfileToLocalStorage(newUser);
          return Observable.of(true);
        })
    }
  })
})
```

}